# RESTEasy and jackson - responsibility division

Tags: json, jackson, resteasy

I have started reading about the Jackson provider for json. I work as a manager these days and have a presentation on JSON soon. We make mobile applications that send JSON data to RESTEasy services.

I understand that the classes on server should be annotated by @Consumes and @Produces and the Content-Type of JSON object should match what a class Consumes.

My doubt is which component performs this logic of reading the content-type of request and find a matching class on server that Consumes that content type? Is it some portion of RESTEasy itself that does this because i couldn't find any such logic in the jackson-jaxrs source. Please let me know.

Also, what points should I cover in the presentation? This is what I plan:
1. JSON syntax
2. Why it is better than XML.
3. the eval() method.
4. Marshaling unmarshaling. 
5. A small demo - JSON and RESTEasy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resteasy is responsible for reading the `Content-Type` header from the request or getting the content type from the url if url content negotiation is being utilized.

Resteasy then matches the path to a method it has scanned and validates that the method supports the content type by evaluating its `@Consumes` annotation.